# How to make TabBar transparent

Tags: xcode, background, transparency, tabbar

I want to make the tabbar transparent and leave the icons still there. So that when you look at it the icons on the tabbar look like they are their by themselves. Whats the code for me to do this? Right now this is the code i have

```
 UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
 [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
 [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 48);

  UIView *trans_view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

  [trans_view setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0
                                       green:0.0
                                        blue:0.0
                                       alpha:0.5]];//you can change alpha value also

  [tabBar1 insertSubview:trans_view atIndex:0];//tabBar1 = your tabbar reference
  [trans_view release];
}
```

this [link](http://www.jondack.com/index.php/2010/12/16/customizing-the-background-of-a-uitabbarcontroller/) also will help you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make a tab bar transparent is by setting the tab bar background image to a transparent image in the interface builder. 
You can get a transparent png image whose height and width is equal to the tab bar's from the net.

Note: By changing the alpha value, you actually end up dimming the tab bar's icons as well. Make sure this is what you want, otherwise using a transparent background image is a better option.